# Video processing software supporting 4 video tracks or more?

Tags: video

Using Pinnacle I sometimes stumble over limitation of 3 video tracks per project. Is there any video software, that has no this limitation or has it lifted up to at least 4-5 video tracks? It's hard to place picture-in-picture, logo and subtitles into video at the same time. And recompressing lowers quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no issues with multiple video tracks in Adobe Premiere - though that does not come cheaply. You might take a look at Sony Vegas, as I believe it's considerably cheaper, but cannot vouch for it's ability to succeed at editing 4+ video tracks - simply that a number of my friends have used it enjoyably and haven't mentioned issues such as this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Vegas
You are correct! No track limitations.